# ActiveMQ - Combining Publish-Subscribe and peer-to-peer

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, publish-subscribe, p2p

Is there a way to implement a topology with ActiveMQ, where P is a publisher, s_a is a subscriber of service A and s_b1 and s_b2 are subscribers of service B. The latter are set in a cluster for load balancing (so s_b1 or s_b2 gets a message but not both).

Is there a way to combine publish-subscribe with a peer-to-peer messaging so one of the subscribers would be a queue which two consumers are listening on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this can be done.

You may want to look at [Apache ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/) which implements [JMS 2.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms2messaging-1954190.html) and support what you ask for out of the box. JMS 2.0 allows multiple subscribers per topic to load balance a cluster.

For ActiveMQ and JMS 1.0 you can use [Virtual Destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) instead. They work with naming conventions.

If you name your topic: `VirtualTopic.StockPrice` and publish messages to it, you will be able to consume from queues named `Consumer.Consumer1.VirtualTopic.StockPrice`, `Consumer.Consumer2.VirtualTopic.StockPrice` etc. Consumer1 can be anything.

You can reconfigure ActiveMQ to use other names for Virtual Destinations (prefix, suffix etc).